# How to remove all classes from a menu except from the actual active element?

Tags: javascript

I have a menu which opens a submenu onclick by adding a class `active` to the corresponding element. However, whenever the first submenu was opened it stayed active if a second submenu was opened and so on.

Therefore I added a `forEach` to first remove all `active` classes and only after that add the `active` class to the next submenu.

Unfortunately, this causes the problem, I can't wrap my head around: **I need the active menu to close if the link is clicked again**.

The following code does not work in this case, because when clicking the same link it will first remove all `active` classes and then add it again which causes the menu to stay open instead of closing.

```
const megamenu = document.querySelector('.megamenu');
const menuSection = megamenu.querySelector('.megamenu-section');  
const submenus = document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu-submenu');

menuSection.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    submenus.forEach(submenu => {
        if (submenu.classList.contains('active')) {
            submenu.classList.remove('active');
            console.log("hasActive")
    })
    e.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

I think I need a way to remove all `active` classes except for the actual active submenu.

Any way to achieve this? Or any better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Please click `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: `const clickedSubMenu = e.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu');` + `if (submenu === clickedSubMenu) return;` in the `.forEach`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, that's actually pretty clever. It seems to work. However, I need to test if there are any unexpected errors. But it's looking good so far. I will come back to you if you don't mind.

Comment: I wouldn't call that clever. It just "skips" the clicked submenu,so the `.toggle()` at the end does what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiple approaches are for demonstration that there are always multiple ways to solve a single problem in programming.
Some might be more efficient, others might be more readable, etc.

You may chose whichever approach you prefer.

### Approach 1 (recommended by me)

Save reference of last active submenu as `lastActive`.
`onclick`, remove `.active` from `lastActive`, and toggle `.active` on clicked submenu.

To fix the case where `lastActive` is the clicked submenu, we toggle depending on if `.active` was present or not before removal on `lastActive`.

This requires no looping, and *almost* no branching (if-statements) from our part (but most likely uses some in the native code (may use some anyway)).
But I think it creates a single [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (no problem).

So that `lastActive` is not visible in the global context *or* the rest of the script, we encapsulate it inside an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```js
const megamenu = document.querySelector('.megamenu');
const menuSection = megamenu.querySelector('.megamenu-section');  
const submenus = document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu-submenu');


(function() {
  let lastActive = submenus[0];
  menuSection.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    const currentSubmenu = evt.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu');
    if (!currentSubmenu) return;
    
    const wasActive = currentSubmenu.classList.contains('active');
    
    lastActive.classList.remove('active');
    currentSubmenu.classList.toggle('active', !wasActive);
    
    lastActive = currentSubmenu;
  });
})();
```

```css
.megamenu-submenu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.megamenu-submenu.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="megamenu">
  <div class="megamenu-section">
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Approach 2

Loop through each active submenu and remove `.active`, except for the currently clicked one. Toggle `.active` of the clicked one.

To only loop through the currently active submenus, we need to query inside the listener. This may hit the performance (minimally) for excessively many elements.

```js
const megamenu = document.querySelector('.megamenu');
const menuSection = megamenu.querySelector('.megamenu-section');  
const submenus = document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu-submenu');

menuSection.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const currentSubmenu = evt.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu');
  if (!currentSubmenu) return;
  
  for (const submenu of document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu-submenu.active')) {
    if (submenu !== currentSubmenu)
      submenu.classList.remove('active');
  }
  currentSubmenu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.megamenu-submenu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.megamenu-submenu.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="megamenu">
  <div class="megamenu-section">
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Approach 3

Similar to approach 2, but loop through the already existing NodeList `submenus`.

This may hit the performance (minimally) for excessively many submenus, but should generally perform better than approach 2.

```js
const megamenu = document.querySelector('.megamenu');
const menuSection = megamenu.querySelector('.megamenu-section');  
const submenus = document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu-submenu');

menuSection.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const currentSubmenu = evt.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu');
  if (!currentSubmenu) return;
  
  for (const submenu of submenus) { // Only changed line
    if (submenu !== currentSubmenu)
      submenu.classList.remove('active');
  }
  currentSubmenu.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.megamenu-submenu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1.6rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.megamenu-submenu.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="megamenu">
  <div class="megamenu-section">
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
    <div class="megamenu-submenu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can minimize your loops by changing `document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu-submenu');` to `document.querySelectorAll('.megamenu-submenu.active');` and move it inside the `on` event, so it calculated on event and that way you only select the active submenus.
Then you know that your current target won't have `.active`, because you removed all of the `.active` so you can just add instead of toggle.

After that just add a check to see whether `e.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu').classList.contains('active')` and if it does, simply remove that class, otherwise do all of the above.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, but only kind of. It only works for the first link in the menu, not sure why. Could you please share a full code example? Thanks

Comment: Because you are adding the event on the parent element and as such the closest to that is the first child. You can change the event listener to the sub menus instead or to whichever element you actually want to be targeted

Answer (score 0):

You can just exempt the clicked submenu from the generic removal:

```
const clickedMenu = e.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu')
for (const submenu of submenus) {
    if (submenu != clickedMenu) {
        submenu.classList.remove('active');
    }
}
clickedMenu.classList.toggle('active');
```

Alternatively shorten it to

```
const clickedMenu = e.target.closest('.megamenu-submenu')
for (const submenu of submenus) {
    submenu.classList.toggle('active', submenu == clickedMenu ? undefined : false);
}
```